# Visual Studio keeps correcting select to Select Case when writing visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm a nerd that likes writing way too many LINQ and SQL queries, so I use the `Select` keyword a bunch. The issue is that sometimes Visual Studio malevolently autocorrects `select` to `Select Case`. For example, it happens when I move to another line sometimes when I have a half-finished LINQ query, and when I start commenting out SQL queries.

Examples:

For a LINQ query (the IEnumerable flavor), suppose that I have a partially completed query:

```
dim three =
  from x in xs
  select
```

If I put my cursor on the `s` in select and press enter, *pow*: it is now `Select Case` instead, which I do not want.

For a SQL query, if I have

```
dim tehQuery = "
select
my_name
from my_funny_table
"
```

If I comment out the `dim` line, *pow*: `Select Case`

I looked in the settings to find some vb specific thing to stop Visual Studio from being hilarious, but I couldn't find which option, if any, autocorrects `select` to `select case`.

I guess that I should also mention that I use VsVim, but I'm not sure if that affects anything. I am using Visual Studio Professional 2019.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Never happened, but this doesn't mean anything. You should specify the Version of Visual Studio in use and a sample LINQ query (I assume LINQ to SQL) that generates the *issue* and maybe also clarify what *I start commenting out SQL queries* in a *half finished* query means, in practice (e.g., the Select command is separated from the rest of the query, because there's an empty line in between etc.)

Comment: Yes, as mentioned before, if you insert a new line between the query and, e.g., a Select clause or method (`dim three = xs.Select(Function(x) x)`), then the token is not considered part of the query, hence it's subject to refactoring. IIRC, this behavior is governed by the `Pretty Listing` option of the Text Editor.

Comment: Is there a way to change what that option affects? If I turn it off, it removes all autocorrecting, and I do rely on the autocorrecting a bunch

Comment: So, you're kind of in a Catch 22 situation here: you don't want the analyzer to fix the syntax, because of your editing habit, but you don't want to suppress it because you want the analyzers to autocorrect the syntax. -- Note that a temporary suppression is generated by typing `CTRL+Z` right after a piece of code has been refactored. Maybe it's enough.

Comment: If you can come up with a way that Visual Studio could parse your intention, despite what you give it to work with, you could suggest alterations to VS ;) Have you tried any alternatives to VS, such as [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/)?

Comment: Ah you guys are right. What is vb supposed to do with a line containing only the word select? I'm lucky that the autoformatter doesn't do more hilarious things. I mostly just use the autoformatter for capitalizing things and adding whitespace, so I should really just bite the bullet and not let VS oppress me any longer with its autoformatter